# How to reference to a element in another Scene

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have two scenes, one who serves as a main scene and one who serves as a wizard.

When the user clicks a button on the `wiz scene`, I want a new tab added to the tabpane in the `main scene`.

The problem is that the program thinks I am referencing to a tabPane in the wizard scene, while it's actually placed in the main scene.

So my question is, **how can I reference to elements in another scene?** (actually another FXML document)

**Note:** I am using scene builder

By the way, I got it to work using : [How do I access a UI element from another controller class in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995359/how-do-i-access-a-ui-element-from-another-controller-class-in-javafx)

But I understand this isn't the recommended approach, so what is?

It could be that I am approaching this all wrong.. But all I want is a new window opening with a button inside, and when the user press the button inside the new window, a new tab should be added to the main window.

Answer (score 0):

### Original content Source:

[JavaFX 8 Tutorial - Part 2: Model and TableView](http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part2/)

---

From this tutorial [about JavaFX](http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part2/), add a method in your controller:

```
/**
 * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
 * 
 * @param mainApp
 */
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;

    // Add observable list data to the table
    personTable.setItems(mainApp.getPersonData());
}
```

Then do as follows:

> ### Connecting MainApp with the PersonOverviewController
>
> The setMainApp(...) method must be called by the MainApp class. This gives us a way to access the MainApp object and get the list of Persons and other things. Replace the showPersonOverview() method with the following. It contains two additional lines:
>
> MainApp.java - new showPersonOverview() method

```
/**
 * Shows the person overview inside the root layout.
 */
public void showPersonOverview() {
    try {
        // Load person overview.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/PersonOverview.fxml"));
        AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);

        // Give the controller access to the main app.
        PersonOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this only related to texts with strings? I have no observablelist,I want to add tabs to a tabpane.